# Collection sort that sort based on class that implements Comparator

Tags: java, compare, comparator, comparable, compareto

I have a problem with Collections sorting, to be more specific

```
Output:
[B_Author: Movie_X, A_Author: Movie_A, A_Author: Movie_B]
Should Be:
[A_Author: Movie_A, A_Author: Movie_B, B_Author: Movie_X]
```

method thats supposed to do that (in class MovieStorage):

```
public Set<Movie> getCatalogue(Comparator<Movie> comp){
        List<Movie> sett = new ArrayList<>(this.movieList);
        sett.sort(comp);
        return new HashSet<>(sett);
    }
```

Class that implements comparator:

```
public class MovieComparator implements Comparator<Movie>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Movie a, Movie b) {
        if (a.getName().compareTo(b.getName()) == 0){
            return a.getAuthor().compareTo(b.getAuthor());
        }
        return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
    }
}
```

called method:

```
System.out.println(movieStorage.getCatalogue(new MovieComparator()));
```

I have been looking around StackOverflow and other webs, but I have noticed that everyone sorts it based on 1 parameter ( which doesnt work for me too ) and at a same time, the code is pretty much the same as mine is ...

Thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: What does the documentation for `HashSet` say about ordering?

Comment: It means that HashSet does not maintains the order of its elements. Hence sorting of HashSet is not possible. .... which mean i cant convert it back to set ... i am such a bakaroo ... thanks ... you can post it as an answer and I will upvote it + check as correct

Comment: You might also use a compare that is more i18n using a collator instead of a binary comparaison of characters. ÉÈÊEéèêe might not ne very close using your "alphabetical" sorting method.

Comment: There are other types of sets that preserve insertion ordering. Linkedhashset for exemple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more compact way to create comparators:

```java
Comparator<Movie> comparator =
    Comparator.comparing(Movie::getName).thenComparing(Movie::getAuthor);

Set<Movie> movies = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
movies.addAll(movieList);
```

And `TreeSet` iterates in sorted order.

To add to the `Movie` class:

```java
public static class Movie implements Comparable<Movie> {
    private static final Comparator<Movie> COMPARATOR =
        Comparator.comparing(Movie::getName).thenComparing(Movie::getAuthor);

    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Movie other) {
        return COMPARATOR.compare(this, other);
    }
}
```

Then the `TreeSet` doesn't need a comparator specified:

```java
Set<Movie> movies = new TreeSet<>(movieList);
```

Comment: You beat me to it!  I was about to make that last comment.